# Spark scala join RDD between 2 datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, join, rdd

Supposed i have two dataset as following:

**Dataset 1:**

```
id, name, score
1, Bill, 200
2, Bew, 23
3, Amy, 44
4, Ramond, 68
```

**Dataset 2:**

```
id,message
1, i love Bill
2, i hate Bill
3, Bew go go !
4, Amy is the best
5, Ramond is the wrost
6, Bill go go
7, Bill i love ya
8, Ramond is Bad
9, Amy is great
```

I wanted to join above two datasets and counting the top number of person's name that appears in dataset2 according to the name in dataset1 the result should be:

```
Bill, 4
Ramond, 2 
..
..
```

I managed to join both of them together but not sure how to count how many time it appear for each person.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Edited: 
my join code:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("dataset1")
val rdd2 = sc.textFile("dataset2")
val rddPair1 = rdd.map { x =>
  var data = x.split(",")
  new Tuple2(data(0), data(1))
}
val rddPair2 = rdd2.map { x =>
  var data = x.split(",")
  new Tuple2(data(0), data(1))
}
rddPair1.join(rddPair2).collect().foreach(f =>{
  println(f._1+" "+f._2._1+" "+f._2._2)
})
```

Comment: How did you joined both the dataset? Share that, counting after joining should be straight forward using reduceByKey or groupByKey

Comment: Thanks for comments @AmitKumar i have added my join code can you have a look at it again please

Comment: Basically you are joining both the dataset on the "id". In the above data in your question, the output of the data based on joining with "id", will have the name "Bill' only once. The output is 4  Ramond  Amy is the best
2  Bew  i hate Bill
3  Amy  Bew go go !
1  Bill  i love Bill .

Comment: In the join, output i dont see name "Bill" appearing for 4 times. confirm your join column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `RDDs`, achieving the solution you desire, would be complex. Not so much using `dataframes`.

First step would be to read the two files you have into `dataframes` as below

```
val df1 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("header", true)
  .load("dataset1")
val df2 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .load("dataset1")
```

so that you should be having

```
df1
+---+------+-----+
|id |name  |score|
+---+------+-----+
|1  |Bill  |200  |
|2  |Bew   |23   |
|3  |Amy   |44   |
|4  |Ramond|68   |
+---+------+-----+

df2
+---+-------------------+
|id |message            |
+---+-------------------+
|1  |i love Bill        |
|2  |i hate Bill        |
|3  |Bew go go !        |
|4  |Amy is the best    |
|5  |Ramond is the wrost|
|6  |Bill go go         |
|7  |Bill i love ya     |
|8  |Ramond is Bad      |
|9  |Amy is great       |
+---+-------------------+
```

`join`, `groupBy` and `count` should give your desired output as

```
df1.join(df2, df2("message").contains(df1("name")), "left").groupBy("name").count().as("count").show(false)
```

Final output would be

```
+------+-----+
|name  |count|
+------+-----+
|Ramond|2    |
|Bill  |4    |
|Amy   |2    |
|Bew   |1    |
+------+-----+
```